# VB Window Auto Resizing to 0 height and 0 width

Tags: vb6

We are utilizing VB code and randomly when a user drags an icon and releases it, a new window should open but instead only the title of the window is visible but the rest of window is set to 0,0 so none of the variables are visible to the user nor does the title have any expansion options.

Comment: Barring psychic abilities, I'm fairly certain you have not provided any useful info to help debug your problem. Some code might be nice. Refer to [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to show the form without the body, just the titlebar with its caption?

For example by the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Click()
  Height = Height - ScaleHeight
End Sub
```

When you run that code and click on the form, it will be resize and only show the titlebar

Pay attention though that nothing weird happens in any Form_Resize event!